# Promises in Node js: how to improve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm working on a coding assignment for node.js and I finished it. However, I am wondering if there is any way to improve upon it. The assignment is to take in 3 promises with JSON objects and merge the data as such.
My code does take in the three promises, resolves them, and merges them according to the specifications. I am worried that the code may be too convoluted. 
Are there any recommendations to improve it?
Thanks!

```
{
  travelers: [
    id,
    name,
    flights: [
      {
        legs: [
          {
            airlineCode,
            airlineName,
            flightNumber,
            frequentFlyerNumber
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

As I said, my code works but I'm wondering if it can be improved. Here is my code.

```
'use strict';

// TODO Import what you need
var tripService = require('./api/trip.service.js');
var profile = require('./api/profiles.service.js');
var airlines = require('./api/airlines.service.js');


function getTravelersFlightInfo() {


  var tripServiceGet= () => tripService.get();
  var profileGet = () =>profile.get();
  var airlinesGet = () => airlines.get();
  var trips = tripServiceGet().then(function(trip){
    return trip;
  });
  var profiles = profileGet().then(function(profile){
    return profile;
  });
  var airline = airlinesGet().then(function(airlines){
    return airlines;
  });

  function assignLegsToTraveler(passengerFlight, legs , airline , ff){
    passengerFlight = {};
    passengerFlight.legs = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < legs.length; i++){
      var airCode = legs[i].airlineCode;
      passengerFlight.legs[i] = {};
      passengerFlight.legs[i].airlineCode = airCode;
      passengerFlight.legs[i].airlineName = airline.airlines.find( x => x.code === airCode).name;
      passengerFlight.legs[i].flightNumber = legs[i].flightNumber;
      if (ff.hasOwnProperty(airCode) === true){
        passengerFlight.legs[i].frequentFlyerNumber = ff[airCode];
      }

    }
    return passengerFlight;
  }

  function assignFlights(passenger, trips, airline, ff){
    for(let i = 0; i < trips.flights.length; i++){
      if(trips.flights[i].travelerIds.includes(passenger.id)){
        passenger.flights[passenger.flights.length] = assignLegsToTraveler(passenger.flights[passenger.flights.length], trips.flights[i].legs, airline, ff);

      }
    }
    return passenger;
  }

  return Promise.all([trips, profiles, airline]).then(function([trips, profiles, airline]) {
    var result = {};
    result.travelers = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < profiles.profiles.length; i++){
      result.travelers[i] = {};
      result.travelers[i].id = profiles.profiles[i].personId;
      result.travelers[i].name = profiles.profiles[i].name;
      result.travelers[i].flights = [];
      assignFlights(result.travelers[i], trips.trip, airline, profiles.profiles[i].rewardPrograms.air);

    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null,2));
    return result;
  });
}
getTravelersFlightInfo();
module.exports = getTravelersFlightInfo;
```

Comment: Perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a more appropriate place to ask

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the part where you initialize profiles, airline and trips is unnecessary, you should be able to simply call promise.all on tripserviceget, profileget and airlines get,  would love to know if that helps! Good luck!

Comment: async await can help you here.

Comment: @DanielA.White how exactly?